# Thesis Topics for DSP using Matlab/Simulink/LabVIEW

Tags: matlab

I am searching for a good thesis topic on DSP with the use Matlab/Simulink/LabVIEW for my master, however, when I contact my department (we only have 1 DSP professor), he asks me to try to propose one but I cannot think of any.

I wonder if someone can help me with some ideas

Comment: Any personal interests?

Comment: @hoknows - I am interested in application of DSP for power system

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd go for something related to Compressed Sensing. Even though my Ph.D. is not on this subject, I've come across it couple of months ago and it looks quite interesting, and it's relatively a new topic too (correct me if i'm wrong). Violating the Nyquist Sampling rate has never been that scientific and fun I suppose. Give it a shot, read a couple of papers (there are really good review papers out there that can give you a good introduction, you might want to visit [this website](http://dsp.rice.edu/cs) for a good start).

Good luck and try to have fun while doing it, that's a must!